# When DRF's field is named "products" it's returned as None

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class OrderProductCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        fields = ('product',)

class OrderProductCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        fields = ('product',)

    class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        products = OrderProductCreateSerializer(many=True, required=True)
```

When field is named `products` I get `None` as result. When field is named as any other string (`products1`) I get valid results.
There is no special processing involved anywhere in code base related to `products`, just a simple `many=True` field.

Comment: You use a `Serializer`, not a `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: Yes. Actually there are other `many=True` fields exist and they work as expected.